# How to benchmark disk IO in PHP? with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, io, benchmarking

Are there any good benchmark test written in PHP that can test Disk IO, preferably involving MySQL?

If I were to write one, how should I write one?

- basic `fwrite()` of random data
- inserting a large number of entry into MySQL and `Avg()` or `Max()` without index?
- zipping a file

If there are any opensource scripts that do these would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DBench is a very simple and lightweight library for generating
>   database tables data and testing it perfomance.
>
> Features:  * Support of MySQL and PostgreSQL  * Tables data generation
>   by customizable randomizers  * Perfomance tests  * Log to CSV  *
>   Generate perfomance chart image like this
>   http://dbench.googlecode.com/files/dbench_chart.png
>
> Project site: http://code.google.com/p/dbench
>
> https://github.com/barbushin/dbench

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834459/35634